# Basic Authentication credentiable readable for programmers/deploying persons

Tags: spring, authentication, header, credentials

I am using the following code snippet for basic authentication in Spring webservices:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();    
String auth = "abcdXX4567" + ":" + "P678546GGhh";    
byte[] encodedAuthorisation = Base64.encode(auth.getBytes());    
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encodedAuthorisation));
```

Developers, deployers and webservice providers know the username and password combination.
 So how this service would be secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Authentication has its own limitations. Its similar to using a username/password for an email service or any other website. If these credentials are compromised in any way the account/service can be accessed by the one who has the credentials.

You can take care of some basic things while implementing this kind of security:

1. Share passwords only a need to know basis
2. Avoid hard coding credentials in code, use from some external configuration
3. Change credentials from time to time

Spring has tons of other options to implement security for web services.

Read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html) to know more.